# How to display data to selected user in android?

Tags: android, listview, firebase

I want to assign `listview` from database to selected user...Let's say when user1 log in it will show `listview` from database1 while user2 log in it will show `listview` from database2... Is it possible to does that?

Comment: "Is it possible?"  Yes.  So what exactly is your specific question?

Comment: @EJK my question is how to do that cause I hardly find tutorial or reference to this

Comment: @JavaGuy The purpose of tutorial and references, is to help you understand the basic concept of the technology. Understand database, and listview, then you will know how to do it. SO is not a place to provide tutorial

Comment: Why do you have one database **per user**?

Comment: @Jacky okay sorry

Comment: @JavaGuy: it's a bit unclear what you're asking. But given that we're dealing with software here, there's a good chance that what you want is possible. To get better, more actionable help I recommend that you update your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such an MCVE is the best way to improve your chances of getting help with code-related questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

**In LoginActivity**

```
yourButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
         String username = yourEditTextUsername.getText().toString();
         Intent intent = new Intent(this,YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);
         intent.putExtra("username",username);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**In YOUR_ACTIVITY**

```
String username;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAY_OUT);
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     if(intent != null){
         username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
         if(username.equals("user1")){
             //get data from database1 and set data to listview 
         } else if (username.equals("user2")){
             //get data from database2 and set data to listview 
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: oh i forget to use the if else statement... thank you